# Custom template for OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm gradually building a custom theme for my first OpenCart site, but I'm having trouble getting a custom template to work. I have some additional code that I was to build into a template, which is then linked to a specific page. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Create a new page under "Catalog/Information" titled "Calculator".
2. Create a custom php/tpl template for that page that contains some custom javascript and php code.
3. Link the two together so that when I visit the "Calculator" page on the front end, I see the introduction text (added via the CMS) at the top of the page, then the results of the custom javascript at the bottom.

Anyone know how to do this? I've been into the template files and the "Design/Layouts" section of the admin and done what seems logical, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an information page via Admin > Catalog > Information. However, you wouldn't be able to include any PHP.

To create a new template you need to add a few files to your project. OpenCart is based on MVC architecture. If you aren't familiar with MVC visit this page.

http://docs.opencart.com/introduction-to-mvc-l

Controller:

Create a file named calculator.php and add it to catalog > controller > information. Then add the following.

```
<?php
class ControllerInformationCalculator extends Controller {
   private $error = array();

     public function index() {
      $this->language->load('information/calculator'); //Optional. This calls for your language file

       $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title')); //Optional. Set the title of your web page.

         $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

         $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
           'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
         'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),           
           'separator' => false
         );

         $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
           'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
         'href'      => $this->url->link('information/calculator'),
           'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
         );   

       $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title'); //Get "heading title" from language file.

      if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/calculator.tpl')) { 
         $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/information/calculator.tpl'; // If the template exists get it
      } else {
         $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not-found.tpl'; //Shows an error if template not found
      }

      $this->children = array(
         'common/column_left',
         'common/column_right',
         'common/content_top',
         'common/content_bottom',
         'common/footer',
         'common/header'
      ); //Required. The children files for the page.

      $this->response->setOutput($this->render());      
     }
}
?>
```

Template:
Create a file named calculator.tpl and add it to catalog > view > theme > (Your Theme Directory) > template > information

Add the following to the template file:

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
<div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>

  ADD YOUR CONTENT HERE

   <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Language:
Create a file named calculator.php and add it to catalog > language > english > information. Add the following to this file:

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']  = 'Calculator';
?>
```

You can add as many language variables as you would like but remember you need to add them in the controller as well. For example:

In the language file:

```
$_['example']  = 'Example Text';
```

In the controller:

```
$this->data['example'] = $this->language->get('example');
```

If you need to call your database you will also need a model similar to the example below. Create a file named calculator.php and add to catalog > model > module.

```
<?php
class ModelModuleCalculator extends Model {
    public function example() {

    }
?>
```

You also need to load the model before you can call it. Add this line to your controller before you call it.

```
$this->load->model('module/calculator');
```

Example model call (also in controller):

```
$this->model_module_calculator->example();
```

Comment: The controller and template part is what I'd tried before and it seemed like I was missing one step to make it all work. I've created both of those again from scratch, using the content you supplied, and also created the language file. Still not working though.

Comment: Is the model part at the bottom optional? You say "if you need to call your database"...?

Comment: Do I need to create a layout and set it as the layout override for the page? I've tried with or without that and can't get it to work.

Comment: I just tested it again. It's working on my end. Here's the path to the page example.com/index.php?route=information/calculator.

If you want to create a layout for this go to your admin panel and navigate to design > layouts and add a Calculator layout. The path will be information/calculator.

You can test this by creating a information page (catalog > information) and overriding the layout on the design tab.

Comment: I've removed the SEO-friendly URL and the path that the URL is pointing to is "information/information", not the calculator one:

http://timkeaydesign.com/nnc/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=8

Comment: Manually typing in the URL you suggest shows the correct template, but there's an error:

http://timkeaydesign.com/nnc/index.php?route=information/calculator

That references an echo for $description - how do I get that working? Is that where the model comes in?

Comment: After you remove the SEO friendly urls it should show information/information. That is actually pointing to the controller not the template. So long as you add the layout override in admin > catalog > information > design it should be working properly. Can you send your tpl (around line 9)? This notice appears to be for a variable that I didn't include above.

Comment: I created a new layout in System > Design > Layouts, called it "Calculator", then set the route as "information/calculator", then saved it. I then went to Catalog > Information and edited the "Calculators" page. I went to the Design tab and selected the "Calculator" layout override, then clicked save. The link in the bottom nav still seems to be ignoring the layout override, though.

Comment: Line 9 of the tpl is just: <?php echo $description; ?>

Comment: Do you need to access this from the admin panel? Do you have multiple calculator pages or is this a single page? If this is a single page and you don't need to access from the admin panel I would be inclined to link to index.php?route=information/calculator and make changes to the tpl directly and wouldn't access it from the admin panel. If you do need multiple pages you could create a module for the admin to create calculator pages. Also, what is the description variable? It needs to be defined in the controller before it can be used in the template. $this->data['description'] = 'example'.

Comment: It's not essential but I thought it was the best way to do it, so that the page description/content (which I was intending to have appear above the calculators) was editable. There are two different calculators which will need their own templates.

Comment: You're right - it's probably easier to link to the information/calculator URL. Is there a way of having that as an SEO-friendly URL? In my mind, that was one of the other added benefits of integrating it into one of the "Information" page templates.

Comment: This page appears to have a vqmod to make these pages SEO friendly. http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=89807. The 4th comment on has a link to the vqmod file. It looks like you'll have to manually add your pages. I haven't tested it but it appears to work for others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65187/discussion-between-timkeay-and-trevor).